# Bound on $e^{-ix}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Is the following bound true for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$?
$$|e^{-ix}| = |\cos(x)+i\sin(x)| \leq 2.$$
Any confirmations or counter-examples are appreciated!

Comment: Actually $|e^{-ix}|=1$, you can see it easily by computing $|e^{-ix}|^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's fine. But it gets better:\begin{align}\left|e^{-ix}\right|&=|\cos(x)-i\sin(x)|\\&=\sqrt{\cos^2x+\sin^2(x)}\\&=1.\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

YEs it is true, but, in fact, the "bound" is better:

$$|\cos x\pm i\sin x|=\sqrt{\cos^2 x+\sin^2x}=\sqrt{1}=1.$$